# Handling images for product upload

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for my project.

I have a product upload form where the user will give the title, categories, description etc. The product is a digital download so they will upload it as well. It's a PDF or .DOC. Next, the form gives the user the ability to upload a picture to represent their product and help them market it on the site. Upon submission the form stores plenty of things to the database including an item id on auto_increment as the primary key, a link to the image of the product and a link to the actual product itself(the PDF or DOC). It is only possible for the user to have 1 image file and 1 product file for each product (or for each row in the database).

I want to create a simple folder structure to handle the uploads. I was thinking something like this example:

```
/Users/JohnDoe/Products/*/Product.pdf
```

and

```
/Users/JohnDoe/Products/*/Image.jpg
```

Where the asterisk is the Item ID.

Here is what I am having trouble figuring out. The item id is not generated until the form is actually submitted and passes validation and then the MySQL auto_increment counter hits. I have to upload my image and product before then because I need form validation on them as well. For example, I need to make sure a user is actually uploading a .PDF file and not something else.

Should I go ahead and submit the form then do validation on the file uploads that way I have access to the item id? If the validation on the file uploads fail then delete the newly submitted item data. If the validation on the file uploads pass do an Update on the MySQL row to add the image links and then rename the files to what I want.

Is there a best practice for handling this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scenario such as this you should treat the file upload no differently to another field.

Building on your described method:

1. The field is still filled out by the user (file to upload selected)
2. The field is still validated and processed by your PHP code, potentially returning to the user to fix their errors
3. Upon validation succeeding the fields data is still stored server side

   1. Create the new record in your database
   2. Retrieve the ID of the newly added row ([MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php) / [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php))
   3. Copy the temporary files to their new location using this ID (creating the folder if required)

The only decision you need to make in this scenario is how to handle a failure when copying the uploaded temporary file to its new location, and one of the best ways to do this is to utilise transactions.

Using transactions ([codeigniter transaction documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html)) you can easily roll back your `INSERT` if the copy of the uploaded temporary file fails.

**Disclaimer** I haven't tested this code, it's just to give you an idea on the flow.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data); 

// COPY UPLOADED FILE HERE, USING $this->db->insert_id(); to get the ID.
// Use a variable such as $file_copy_success to store true/false based on result of the copy

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE && $file_copy_success === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

So in this example the following happens

1. Transaction started
2. `INSERT` attempted
3. Retrieval of insert_id
4. Copy of uploaded temporary file to new home
5. On failture rollback `INSERT` query.
6. On success, commit `INSERT` query

If you find there is specific information from the files you need alongside the new row you've inserted, run an `UPDATE` between the file copy and the success/failure test. Then on any failures, that too will be rolled back.